# MSAL and Graph API - access a user's calendar without user interaction?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have an app that runs in a conference room kiosk that displays the conference room's calendar.  Right now the app uses the Interactive Credentials Flow to interactively get the room account's token and then fetch the calender.  By managing refresh & access tokens we should never have to sign in again and re-grant access.

However - we need to deploy this app to 300 rooms.  Sending a technician around to each room and signin with each room's account and grant access is very costly.  Also if ever the refresh or access token goes stale or is revoked, we have to send out a tech to the conference room.  Some conference rooms are in building where there is no tech in the city.

Is there a way we can do this centrally?  To get an access token for a user for granted permissions, then feed this to our application?

We looked at using the "Client Credentials - Application Secrets Flow", but this requires giving the app access to the entire enterprise's calendars.  This we cannot do as many of the users require high security.

Answer (score 0):

I find this an interesting question. 
here is the documentation on how to achieve this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access
You would use application secret auth, but using this, you can limit which mailboxes the graph calls can access. this would be the most elegant way I believe.

Comment: Thanks.  We have see that doc and have implemented it.  It gets close, but not all the way there, as one policy applies to the entire application for the tenant.  What this means is - for my example, each account used in the room can see each other room accounts.

Comment: thats correct, but does it really matter? since they're public kiosks, at worst they can see other public kiosks schedules..  in your code you can just generate device id, then match that with a mailbox. but other than doing it this way. the only other flow you can use is the ROPC flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc but per the guidance, you are never supposed to store the credentials...